# Javascript - Getting propriety from object in var on for loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, arraylist

I'm trying to get a value from an object inside a for loop on Javascript.

What I currently have:

```
    for(var sr in USERS) {
      console.log(sr + " IS " sr.hasOwnProperty("username"));
    }
```

Where USERS is an array of Objects with different values, and one of them is username.

This keeps returning "(value of sr on USERS) IS false";

Comment: `sr` with ether be a string primitive, it will not have any own properties. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to see if that propriety exists on the object sr that is on my array USERS, it should, but it's saying it doesn't.

Comment: `sr` is not an object, it is a property name.

Comment: Yes, now I see the problem. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript `foreach` ( `for(x in y)` ) iterates over keys or indexes, not values so

```
for(var sr in USERS) {
  console.log(sr + " IS " + USERS[sr].hasOwnProperty("username"));
}
```

Comment: well, that returns [Object objec] IS true, but if I do .getOwnPropertyNames("username"); that returns an error (TypeError: undefined is not a function)

Comment: Try `USERS[sr].username` for get `username` value.